# I would like to check if url redirects to another page in R

Tags: r, http, url

I need to check if the url redirects to another page in R. Is it possible ?

Comment: I tried Get() but its quite slow .. is there any other other alternative. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the `httr` package, and there the `GET` function:

```
> library(httr)
> names(GET("http://www.stackoverflow.com"))
[1] "url"         "handle"      "status_code" "headers"     "cookies"
[6] "content"     "times"       "config"     
> GET("http://www.stackoverflow.com")$status_code
[1] 200
```

Comment: `HEAD()` would be more efficient since you don't care about the content.

Comment: @hadley: A particular server returned 404 with `HEAD` and 200 with `GET`, for the same URL. Is this common, or just an exceptionally badly configured server?

Comment: Badly configured server

Comment: This returns 200 for a page that succesfully redirects, instead of 300. E.g., `httr::HEAD("https://ucalgary.ca")` returns `statuscode = 200` but with `url` `https://www.ucalgary.ca`. The first element of `HEAD(xxx)$times` is named `redirect`, etc etc.

Answer (score 4):

### Use `HEAD` as suggested, but check the url from the returned object and the url you input are the same

```
url <- "https://google.ca/"
stat <- httr::HEAD(url)
stat
Response [https://www.google.ca/]
  Date: 2018-02-17 13:57
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
<EMPTY BODY>
stat$times
     redirect    namelookup       connect   pretransfer starttransfer         total 
     0.054985      0.000030      0.000033      0.000109      0.082320      0.137389
```

The first element of `times` is `redirect`. I can't always be sure a redirected page will look like this, so I'd just check the `url` and `HEAD(url)$url` are the same:

```
HEAD(url)$url == url
[1] FALSE # FALSE for redirect
```

Note that pages that add `/` to the end of your urls are also considered redirects:

```
HEAD("https://www.google.ca")$url == "https://www.google.ca"
[1] FALSE
HEAD("https://www.google.ca/")$url == "https://www.google.ca/"
[1] TRUE
```

So you might want to process the returned url if you care about whether little things like that are considered redirects or not.